# append small data frame to a big one and sort it

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, dictionary, append

I have a very large data frame with over 200k records and 7 columns. 
I created another data frame in another function, and I made sure that the new data frame has the exact same 7 columns' names.
The information in the new data frame is extra details for some entries in the big data frame, so I need to sort it inside of the big one and not just append it at the end. 
so after the records are attached, the whole data frame should be sorted by the values in column 'A', there will be many repeats for each value in that column and that is ok, but then I want these lines to be sorted by column 'B'.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: So you can `pd.merge` both dataframes and then sort them using `sort_values(['A','B'])`

Comment: how to append the small df into the big one and have it sorted by two columns, first A and then B.

Comment: @MorZamir - you could follow with what @yatu specifies, May I know why are you saying small and big df here? there is no separate method to concat large and small df in pandas. for any df concat operation either you could use `concat` or `append`. If you are unable to concat with pandas because of large data use `dask`

Comment: You may which to use `pd.concat` and then sort_values as @yatu suggested.

Comment: I wanted to make it clear that all the lines in the small ones should be inserted in many locations inside the big one.

Comment: @MorZamir - both df contains same columns right?

Comment: @MohamedThasinah that is correct.

Comment: @MorZamir - If both column are identical then the above method works :-) make a try

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) & [`sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html)

```
df = pd.concat([big_df, small_df]).sort_values(['A', 'B'])
```